# Find the previous and after raw in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `stop` table, after finding the stop name I want to find the previous and after data `name, lat, longi` of this name.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, 
longi double(10,6)NOT NULL)
```

[image]

For example if the name is `TEST` I want to get the name, lat and longi of ABC and sky. It should even work when there is difference between the `stop_id` like `2,5,7,12`

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT stop_id, name, lat, longi, rn
FROM (
   SELECT stop_id, name, lat, longi,
          @r:=@r+1 AS rn
   FROM stops, (SELECT @r:=0) var
   ORDER BY stop_id, name ) s
WHERE name != 'TEST' AND
      rn >= (SELECT row_number
             FROM (
               SELECT name, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number
               FROM stops, (SELECT @row_number:=0) var
               ORDER BY stop_id, name ) s
               WHERE name = 'TEST' ) - 1     
ORDER BY stop_id LIMIT 2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e11b8/1)

This query:

```
SELECT name, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number
FROM stops, (SELECT @row_number:=0) var
ORDER BY stop_id, name
```

is used twice to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` window function not available in MySQL. Using it we can identify 'row number' of record having `name = 'TEST'` and use this info to get the records we want.

Comment: It was a mistake but now when I execute it the first block `above Demo here` I am getting just the previous one and not the one after too?

Comment: @TheTime What do you mean by *first block*?

Comment: I mean this block which starts with `SELECT stop_id, name, lat, longi, rn` and not the second one which starts with `SELECT name, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number`

Comment: @TheTime Can you set up an sql fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: What I cant unserstand why I am getting two result records when the name is `ABC` but just one when the name `new` is?

Comment: @TheTime `new` is the *last* record, hence there is only a previous record and no *next* record. That's why you get only one result in this case.

Comment: @TheTime Check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e11b8/7). You can play around with `rn`, `row_number` and `cnt` in the `WHERE` clause of your query to get any result you want.

Comment: and `ABC`  is the first one so there is just next records but I am getting 2 next records `TEST, sky`and not just one `TEST`?

Comment: @TheTime Check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e11b8/29). It provides a generic solution for all cases.

Comment: I still have the problem with the first name `XYZ` in your fiddle solution I am getting `ABC, Test` as result also still the both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78650/discussion-between-giorgos-betsos-and-the-time).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ids of the previous and next stops using correlated subqueries, assuming that these are the ones with adjacent ids:

```
select s.*,
       (select s2.stop_id
        from stops s2
        where s2.stop_id < s.stop_id
        order by s2.stop_id desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_stop_id,
       (select s2.stop_id
        from stops s2
        where s2.stop_id > s.stop_id
        order by s2.stop_id ASC
        limit 1
       ) as next_stop_id
from stops s;
```

You can then use `join` to bring in additional information.

It is tempting to use `join`s for getting the prev/next stops, such as:

```
select  s.*, prevstop.*
from stops s left join
     stops prevstop
     on s.stop_id = prevstop.stop_id + 1;
```

However, this assumes that there are no gaps in the values, and that assumption may not be true.

Answer (score 0):

as @Gordon-Linoff mentioned self joins is a good trick to achieve this:

```
SELECT ss . * , nex.stop_id AS nex_id, nex.name AS nex_name, nex.lat AS nex_lat, nex.longi AS nex_longi
FROM (
    SELECT s . * , pre.stop_id AS pre_id, pre.name AS pre_name, pre.lat AS pre_lat, pre.longi AS pre_longi
    FROM stops s
    LEFT JOIN stops pre ON s.stop_id = pre.stop_id + 1) AS ss
LEFT JOIN stops nex ON ss.stop_id = nex.stop_id - 1
WHERE (ss.name LIKE 'TEST')
LIMIT 1
```